# Pandas - Add column containing metadata about the row

Tags: python, loops, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I want to add a column to a Dataframe that will contain a number derived from the number of NaN values in the row, specifically: one less than the number of non-NaN values in the row.

I tried:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    count = row.value_counts()
    val = sum(count) - 1
    df['Num Hits'] = val
```

Which returns an error:

```
-c:4: SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_index,col_indexer] = value instead
```

and puts the first *val* value into every cell of the new column. I've tried reading about .loc and indexing in the Pandas documentation and failed to make sense of it. I gather that .loc wants a row_index and a column_index but I don't know if these are pre-defined in every dataframe and I just have to specify them somehow or if I need to "set" an index on the dataframe somehow before telling the loop where to place the new value, *val*.

Answer (score 1):

You can totally do it in a vectorized way without using a loop, which is likely to be faster than the loop version:

```
In [89]:

print df
          0         1         2         3
0  0.835396  0.330275  0.786579  0.493567
1  0.751678  0.299354  0.050638  0.483490
2  0.559348  0.106477  0.807911  0.883195
3  0.250296  0.281871  0.439523  0.117846
4  0.480055  0.269579  0.282295  0.170642
In [90]:
#number of valid numbers - 1
df.apply(lambda x: np.isfinite(x).sum()-1, axis=1)
Out[90]:
0    3
1    3
2    3
3    3
4    3
dtype: int64
```

@DSM brought up an good point that the above solution is still not fully vectorized. A vectorized form can be simply `(~df.isnull()).sum(axis=1)-1`.

Comment: That isn't fully vectorized, though, because of the `apply`.  Something like `np.isfinite(df).sum(axis=1)-1` should bypass all Python loops.

Comment: Right, `(~df.isnull()).sum(axis=1)-1` will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `index` variable that you define as part of the for loop as the row_index that .loc is looking for:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    count = row.value_counts()
    val = sum(count) - 1
    df.loc[index, 'Num Hits'] = val
```